# Timer textview display not always showing decreasing values, not synchronized

Tags: android, multithreading, synchronized, ui-thread

So I'm trying to create a simple timer app that outputs the elapsed time to the screen. I'm trying to incorporate a pause button. It seems to work, except when pause button is pressed closed to values of x:x:1~ (min:sec:milli) if you unpause and repause rapidly again the next displayed value will be around x:x:N (N > 1) rather than x:x-1:9~. Logcat output below. DISPLAY is the time displayed (time remaining, SHOULD be always decreasing but its not). Elapsed time is the internal time elapsed (always increasing, so looks like that is ok)

```
    10-09 23:28:16.152: D/ClockView(16547): ELAPSED TIME 1728
    10-09 23:28:16.152: D/ClockView(16547): DISPLAY 0:8:272
    10-09 23:28:16.252: D/ClockView(16547): ELAPSED TIME 1829
    10-09 23:28:16.252: D/ClockView(16547): DISPLAY 0:8:171
    10-09 23:28:16.282: D/ClockView(16547): PAUSE PRESSED
    10-09 23:28:16.983: D/ClockView(16547): PAUSE PRESSED
    10-09 23:28:16.983: D/ClockView(16547): ELAPSED TIME 1868
    10-09 23:28:16.983: D/ClockView(16547): DISPLAY 0:8:132
    10-09 23:28:17.083: D/ClockView(16547): ELAPSED TIME 1968
    10-09 23:28:17.083: D/ClockView(16547): DISPLAY 0:8:32
    10-09 23:28:17.123: D/ClockView(16547): PAUSE PRESSED
    10-09 23:28:21.348: D/ClockView(16547): PAUSE PRESSED
    10-09 23:28:21.348: D/ClockView(16547): ELAPSED TIME 2010
    10-09 23:28:21.348: D/ClockView(16547): DISPLAY 0:7:990
    10-09 23:28:21.448: D/ClockView(16547): ELAPSED TIME 2110
    10-09 23:28:21.448: D/ClockView(16547): DISPLAY 0:7:890
```

Code below:

```
public class ClockCallable implements Callable<Long> {

    private long startTime = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime();
    private long elapsedTime = 0;
    private long pausedStartTime = 0;
    private long pausedTime = 0;        

    Object o = new Object();
    private volatile boolean paused = false;

    public void pause() {
        paused = true;
        synchronized(o) {
            pausedStartTime = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime();
        }
    }
    public void resume() {
        paused = false;
        synchronized(o) {
            pausedTime = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() - pausedStartTime;
            startTime += pausedTime;

            o.notifyAll();              
        }
    }

    public void reset() {
        paused = false;
        synchronized(o) {
            clockCallable.startTime = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime();
            clockCallable.elapsedTime = 0;
            clockCallable.pausedStartTime = 0;
            clockCallable.pausedTime = 0;

            o.notifyAll();              
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Long call() throws Exception {

        try {               
            while (elapsedTime < maxTime && !Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {

                if (!paused) {
                    elapsedTime = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() - startTime;
                    Log.d(TAG, "ELAPSED TIME " + elapsedTime);
                    handler.post(new Runnable() { //To post to UI thread
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            synchronized(o) {
                                updateTextView(elapsedTime);
                            }
                        }
                    });

                    Thread.sleep(100); //Prevent too much work on its main thread
                    if (Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
                        return (long) -1; //For future.cancel() handling
                    }
                }
                else {
                    try {
                        while(paused) {
                            synchronized(o) {
                                o.wait();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    catch (InterruptedException e) {}
                }

            }           
        }
        catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return (long) -1; //For future.cancel() handling
        }

        return (long) 1;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Never mind, I solved the problem. It was a problem with the way the display text was formatted. Wound up having nothing to do with the synchronization. Spent too long looking in the wrong place.